Запуск React приложения через файл
Мне необходимо создать React приложение с несколькими дополнительными библиотеками, которое будет открываться через файл (без редактора кода). То есть нужно скинуть человеку папку с приложением, которое запустится при клике по файлу. Видел вариант npm run build с созданием homepage в package.json, но у меня он не срабатывает в проекте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли вообще подобное.

Возможно. Запускаете html из папки build и должно работать. Другой вопрос, какие действия вы там хотите совершать, т.к. есть ограничения на функционал, запущенный через протокол file

Так и делаю, запуск через index html в папке билда выдает белую страницу без кода приложения. Действий на сайте не много: две странички и несколько гет запросов, данные из которых должны выводиться в таблице

Get post будет запрещен. Проверьте, у вас в консоли разработчика должны быть ошибки или во вкладке сеть

Пока что даже самих запросов еще нет, сделал только часть верстки компонентов. на страницах. В консоли выдает лишь предупреждение о том, что скоро обновление реакт роутера до 7 версии с измененным функционалом. Но если исходить из вашего комментария выше, то мое приложение на реакте все равно не получится создать с гет запросами, чтобы открывалось из файла?

Скорее всего да. Вы откройте у себя ваш билд, откройте консоль разработчика и смотрите, что там не так. Может банально пути до js css указаны не верно

Хорошо, спасибо большое!
